# How do I concatenate two textboxes in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am adding rows to my table and the address will be a concatenation of Street, City, State, and Zip.  Right now I have this.

```
    $tr.find('.name').text($('#txtPropName').val());
    $tr.find('.address').text($('#txtPropAddress', ", ", '#txtPropCity', " ", '#txtPropState', " ", '#txtPropZip').val());
    $tr.find('.phone').text($('#txtPropHPhone' + "<br/>" + '#txtPropWPhone').val());
```

No luck on either phone or address.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
$('#txtPropHPhone' + "<br/>" + '#txtPropWPhone')
```

is basically telling jQuery to look for an element named `'#txtPropHPhone<br/>#txtPropWPhone'`.

You'll need to break out the individual elements into separate jQuery requests.

```
$('#txtPropHPhone').val() + '<br/>' + $(txtPropWPhone').val();
```

Comment: @Paul Alexander - The code is better now, but the "<br/>" and '<br/>' tag is returned as a string... am I missing something?

Comment: Use $tr.find('.phone').html(...) instead of $tr.find('.phone).text(...). text() is encoding its parameter, whereas html() will not.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you get the val()s seperately?

```
$tr.find('.phone').text($('#txtPropHPhone').val() + "<br/>" + $('#txtPropWPhone').val());
```

Comment: @easement - The code is better now, but the "<br/>" and '<br/>' tag is returned as a string... am I missing something?