# How do I merge text and html MVC?

Tags: jquery

I have two phone numbers and would like to have the Home Phone on one line and Work phone on the other.  This is what I have so far...

```
$tr.find('.phone').text($('#txtPropHPhone').val()) + '<br />' + $('#txtPropWPhone').val());
```

The .html is still not working... How do I fix this?

Comment: you got the answer in your last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366212/how-do-i-concatenate-two-textboxes-in-jquery-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: What type of element are you selecting with '.phone'? If its an input or form ele, try using val() instead of text()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra parentheses. Try this...

```
$tr.find('.phone').html($('#txtPropHPhone').val() + '<br />' + $('#txtPropWPhone').val());
```